# What is result of gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().currentUser.get().grant()

Tags: javascript, google-api-js-client

Any idea what is the result of calling method `gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().currentUser.get().grant()` in Google gapi javascript library?

I'm trying to implement incremental authorization using Google gapi.auth2 library, but struggling with what method `GoogleUser.grant(options)` actually returns.

Documentation refers to `signIn` method, which returns `Promise<GoogleUser>`.
https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/reference#googleusergrantoptions

Tried to test it, but the result seems quite different...

Answer (score 0):

There is no result. The `grant()` method is somewhat an alias for the `signIn()` method. The difference is that it has been designed to request additional scopes, as how [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/incremental-auth) explains. This is perfect when using the `popup` value for the `ux_mode` option.

Let say for example, a user already has access to your app with basic scopes, but then there is a button that will allow the user to interact with drive. When clicking that button, something like this would happen:

```
  const user = googleAuth.currentUser.get();
  const scopes = user.getGrantedScopes().split(" ");
  if(!scopes.includes("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive")){
    user.grant({
      scope: "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive",
    }).then(()=>{
      console.log(user.getGrantedScopes());
      //do whatever you need to do in drive
    });
  }
```

I hope you get the basic Idea. I'm not really good at explaining stuff but hope this might help.

Comment: thanks, but there is something this method returns. Try 
`user.grant({scope: "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"}).then((res)=>{console.log('Result',res);});`

Comment: yeah... if it has a then method... it returns a promise a `Promise<void>` to be more specific, so you can execute a callback.